# Using 'typedef struct' in classes

Tags: c++

I tried to use 'typedef struct' in a class this way.
Can you expect what I wanted?
As you can see, this doesn't seem possible.
Is it really impossible or not?

```
class CTestStructure
{
public:
    typedef struct stTestInClass;
    StTestInClass   mmm;    // Compile error C3646
};

struct CTestStructure::stTestInClass
{
    int i;
}StTestInClass;

int main()
{
    CTestStructure testStructure;
}
```

Comment: `typedef struct stTestInClass;` doesn't make much sense in C++ (naming an anonymous `struct`). `struct stTestInClass;` would be sufficient. Though, `StTestInClass   mmm;` is using an incomplete `struct` as member. That doesn't work.

Comment: Btw. additionally, there is a typo in `typedef struct stTestInClass;`: The first `s` has to be uppercase.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, the reason I wanted to add 'typedef' was to allow other classes to use this structure type like CTestStructure::StTestInClass aaa;

Comment: @SungsuKim You don't need a typedef to use a struct tag as a typename like that in C++.  `struct stTestInClass { int i; };` and then `CTestStructure::stTestInClass` will work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you don't need `typedef` for structures. A `struct` is just the same as a `class`, but with `public` access being the default.

Secondly, to be able to define a non-pointer or non-reference variable, you need the full definition of the type (the structure).

The natural solution is to simply define the structure inline in the class:

```
class CTestStructure
{
public:
    struct stTestInClass
    {
        int i;
    };

    stTestInClass   mmm;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but in C++ you do not need to use typedef for structs like you need in C(in order to get rid of the "struct" keyword). There your problem is the fact that you have a member of type StTestInClass which is an anonymous type(you just mention its name, it's just a declaration without a definition). You can use it this way, but your member must be a pointer to a StTestInClass object and define this struct elsewhere later or you can define the StTestInClass struct before using it and have a member of type StTestInClass in your class the way you did.